# DialogPreference summary in preference screen

Tags: java, android

Hi!

I have a preference screen holding a DialogPreference. When the preference screen comes visible, i want the DialogPreference to have the current time as summary. How can this be achieved? It could be done via xml, but i can't set the current time in the xml file. I tried to set the summary in the onSetInitialValue method, but it doesn't seem to work, as the summary isn't shown.

Here's my code:(In the example below i'm using a string of random text instead of the current time so i don't have to paste the long function that calculates time).

```
public class TimePreference extends DialogPreference {

  private TimePicker timePicker;
  Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
  private int hour = calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
  private int minute = calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE);


  public TimePreference(Context context, AttributeSet attributes) {
    super(context, attributes);
    setPersistent(false);
    //setSummary(getFormatedTime(hour, minute));
  }

  /**
   * Initialize time picker to currently stored time preferences.
   * 
   * @param view
   * The dialog preference's host view
   */
  @Override
  public void onBindDialogView(View view) {
    super.onBindDialogView(view);
    timePicker = (TimePicker) view.findViewById(R.id.time_picker);
    timePicker.setIs24HourView(DateFormat.is24HourFormat(timePicker.getContext()));
    timePicker.setCurrentHour(hour);
    timePicker.setCurrentMinute(minute);
  }

  /**
   * Handles closing of dialog. If user intended to save the settings, selected
   * hour and minute are stored in the preferences with keys KEY.hour and
   * KEY.minute, where KEY is the preference's KEY.
   * 
   * @param okToSave
   * True if user wanted to save settings, false otherwise
   */
  @Override
  protected void onDialogClosed(boolean okToSave) {
    super.onDialogClosed(okToSave);

    if (okToSave) {
      timePicker.clearFocus();
      SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getEditor();
      hour = timePicker.getCurrentHour();
      minute = timePicker.getCurrentMinute();
      editor.putInt(getKey() + ".hour", hour);
      editor.putInt(getKey() + ".minute", minute);
      editor.commit();

      setSummary(getFormatedTime(hour, minute));
    }

  }

  @Override
    protected void onSetInitialValue(boolean restoreValue, Object defaultValue) {
      super.onSetInitialValue(restoreValue, defaultValue);
      setSummary("current time here!"); // THIS IS NEVER SHOWN ?? WHY ? 
  }
```

}

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

In onCreate after addPreferencesFromResource

```
Preference dialogPref = findPreference(ID for dialog in xml);
dialogPref.setSummary(current time here);
```